# Javascript: Questions about using "Const," for lists and objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, constants

Naturally I assumed the "const," keyword meant the value of a variable could not change, and when it comes to integers and strings that seems to be the case. However, today I was watching a video and somebody type the following

```
const my_list = [];

my_list.push(someValue);
```

I was surprised to find out that this kind of code actually works, as I was under the assumption that the list would be constant. So my question is: Why? What advantage does declaring the list as constant have if you are just going to change it anyways?

Comment: You can no longer do `my_list = ['some other array']`. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#Description

Comment: The _variable_ is constant. Not the list itself. The advantage is that you can never end up with losing the reference. For example imagine another piece of code using `const the_list = my_list`, then the contents of `the_list` would be updated as long as you'd use `my_list.push`, but you would "split the timeline" by doing `my_list = my_list.concat(...)` for example. With `const` the latter would not be allowed.

Comment: `const` doesn't make the actual value immutable, it just means you can't re-assign something to the constant. It's beneficial because it reduces the risk of bugs and unintended side-effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you assign variable with string/number/boolean variable contains the value of string/number/boolean, but then you assign  variable with object or array variable contains the address of that object/array in 'memory'.Then you push something in array the value of variable is still same address of array in memory , and that is why you not get error